# Циклы в Python. Как сделать цикл в XML?

Tags: python, xml, циклы

Есть код.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, traceback, os

sys.path.insert(0, '../')

import pymysql.cursors
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

def select():
    connect = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='qwewqer', password='w1g-wqerwqr', db='wqerqweqwer', charset='utf8mb4')
    product = "product"
    try:
        with connect.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(""" select posts.ID, prodmeta.sku, posts.post_title, prodmeta.min_price, prodmeta.max_price, prodmeta.stock_quantity, prodmeta.stock_status
                                from cms_wp_posts as posts 
                                right join cms_wp_wc_product_meta_lookup as prodmeta 
                                on prodmeta.product_id = posts.ID
                                where posts.post_type = '%s' """ % product)
            
            res = cursor.fetchall()
            print(res)
            if res:
                count = 0
                n = len(res)
                print(n)
                while count < n:
                    offer = ET.Element('offer')
                    isower_id = ET.SubElement(offer, 'isower_id')
                    isower_id.text = str(int(res[0]))
                    article = ET.SubElement(offer, 'article')
                    article.text = str(res[1])
                    title = ET.SubElement(offer, 'title')
                    title.text = str(res[2])
                    code = ET.SubElement(offer, 'code')
                    code.text = 'RU-ALT'
                    min_price = ET.SubElement(offer, 'min_price')
                    min_price.text = str(int(res[3]))
                    max_price = ET.SubElement(offer, 'max_price')
                    max_price.text = str(int(res[4]))
                    stock_id = ET.SubElement(offer, 'stock_id')
                    stock_id.text = str(res[5])
                    available = ET.SubElement(offer, 'available')
                    available.text = str(res[6])        
                    city = ET.SubElement(offer, 'city')
                    city.text = 'Алтайскмй край, г. Бийск'
                    addres = ET.SubElement(offer, 'addres')
                    addres.text = 'отсутствует'
                    pickup = ET.SubElement(offer, 'pickup')
                    pickup.text = '1'
                    active = ET.SubElement(offer, 'active')
                    active.text = '1'
                    count += 1

                    save_xml('new.xml', offer)

            else:
                print("Container is empty!")

    except Exception as e:
        connect.close()
        print("Ошибка: "+str(e)+"")
    finally:
        connect.close()

def save_xml(filename, xml_code):
    xml_string = ET.tostring(xml_code).decode()
    xml_prettyxml = minidom.parseString(xml_string).toprettyxml()
    with open(filename, 'w') as xml_file:
        xml_file.write(xml_prettyxml)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    select()
```

Как сделать чтобы в XML загружалась информация из базы ?

Необходимо получить файл в таком формате

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<offer>
    <offers>
        <isower_id>123</isower_id>
        <article>тест1</article>
        <title>фыаыва</title>
        <code>RU-ALT</code>
        <min_price>115.0</min_price>
        <max_price>115.0</max_price>
        <stock_id>12</stock_id>
        <available>instock</available>
        <city>Алтайскмй край, г. Бийск</city>
        <addres>отсутствует</addres>
        <pickup>1</pickup>
        <active>1</active>
    </offers>
    <offers>
        <isower_id>123</isower_id>
        <article>тест2</article>
        <title>йцукен</title>
        <code>RU-ALT</code>
        <min_price>116.0</min_price>
        <max_price>117.0</max_price>
        <stock_id>12</stock_id>
        <available>instock</available>
        <city>Алтайскмй край, г. Бийск</city>
        <addres>отсутствует</addres>
        <pickup>1</pickup>
        <active>1</active>
    </offers>
</offer>
```

Comment: Потому что приветствия нисколько не добавляют вопросу ценности. Лишь отвлекают.

Comment: Вот вы пишете "Если я использую cursor.fetchone() тогда всё работает". Так в чем же проблема тогда? Непонятно что вам нужно.

Comment: fetchone работает в том случае если я выбрал из БД одну запись. Мне необходимо получить XML с помощью fetchall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо всего вот этого вот огорода:

```
res = cursor.fetchall()
print(res)
if res:
    count = 0
    n = len(res)
    print(n)
    while count < n:
```

Сделайте так:

```
res_all = cursor.fetchall()
print(len(res_all))
for res in res_all:
```

Но вот как правильно в XML сам элементы добавлять - это я уже не подскажу, к сожалению. И записывать XML надо, конечно, уже после цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @CrazyElf , я сделал так

```
res_all = cursor.fetchall()
            print(len(res_all))
            if res_all:
                offer = ET.Element('offer')
                for res in res_all:
                    offers = ET.SubElement(offer, 'offers')
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'isower_id').text = str(res['ID'])
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'article').text = str(res['sku'])
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'title').text = str(res['post_title'])
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'code').text = 'RU-ALT'
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'min_price').text = str(int(res['min_price']))
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'max_price').text = str(int(res['max_price']))
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'stock_id').text = str(res['stock_quantity'])
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'available').text = str(res['stock_status'])
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'city').text = 'Алтайскмй край, г. Бийск'
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'addres').text = 'отсутствует'
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'pickup').text = '1'
                    ET.SubElement(offers, 'active').text = '1'
                
                save_xml('new.xml', offer)
```